# Does express-rate-limit work on server requests from client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client-server, express-rate-limit

So I have a web app I've built with react and javascript that consists of a server side and a client side.
This is what I set up on the server app.js:

```html
require("./DB/connectToDb");
// require("./primeryData/primeryCards")();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

const usersRouter = require("./Routes/Users/userRouter");
const cardsRouter = require("./Routes/Cards/cardsRouter");
const ordersRouter = require("./Routes/Orders/OrderRouter");

const chalk = require("chalk");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(morgan(chalk.cyan(":method :url :status :response-time ms")));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/api/cards", cardsRouter);
app.use("/api/orders", ordersRouter);

const PORT = 8181;
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(chalk.blueBright.bold(`server run on: http://:localhost:${PORT}`))
);

const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    max: 10, // Limit each IP to 100 requests per `window` (here, per 15 minutes)
    message: "Limited I Guess..."
})

app.get("/",limiter,(req,res)=>res.send(req.ip));


app.use('/api', limiter);
```

When I go to the Browser with http://localhost:8181/ I get my IP which is ::1
After refreshing >10 times I get "Limited I Guess..." as it should.
However when I try and use my client side to make requests nothing happens, I can make a million server calls!!!
Am I missing something? Does express-rate-limit not work when client side is making the server calls?
An example of my server api:

```html
/********** Like/Dislike Card **********/

router.patch("/card-like/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // console.log(req.params.id);
    const user = req.user;
    let card = await Card.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });

    const cardLikes = card.likes.find((id) => id === user._id);

    if (!cardLikes) {
      card.likes.push(user._id);
      card = await card.save();
      return res.send(card);
    }

    const cardFiltered = card.likes.filter((id) => id !== user._id);
    card.likes = cardFiltered;
    card = await card.save();
    return res.send(card);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright("Could not edit like:", error.message));
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the library in app.js, tried using it in api.js and worked I guess, app.js was unaware of what was going on in api.js even though it was required.

Comment: If you want to add additional details to your question, please edit the original question instead of posting a reply. Thanks!